# Unable to Interrupt bulk update (inserts) to a list from a stream

Tags: c#, multithreading, system.reactive

Edit: To simplify things here is the paradigm: I have an list of items that is constantly being updated by a continuous stream. Every now and then, I get a new data snapshot that re-initializes the stream. As a result if there are any updates happening while I want to re-initialize, I need to make sure that these updates stop and the new snapshot is being used.

I am dealing with a number of continuous data streams of updates that needs to be displayed to the UI.
The updates need to be displayed in reverse order i.e. the most recent update goes on top of the list.
In order to display the result on top I have to insert into the list.
The problem that I have that sometime the list needs to be rest (i.e. List.Clear), however, if I am mid insert, I need to stop it, because otherwise Inserting will cause an exception.

I've put together a reactive method to help me with that, however, it seems to be ignoring my *until* stream.

```
public static IObservable<T> BufferAndDispatchUntil<T, TStopUnit>(
                             this IObservable<T> source, 
                             Action<T> onNext, 
                             IScheduler scheduler, 
                             IObservable<TStopUnit> until, 
                             DispatcherPriority dispatcherPriority = DispatcherPriority.Background)
{
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        if (onNext == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("onNext");

        if (Application.Current == null)
            return source.Do(onNext);

        var dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;

        return source
            .LazyBuffer(BufferTime, BufferCount, scheduler)
            .TakeUntil(until)
            .Do(b => dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => b.ForEach(onNext), dispatcherPriority))
            .SelectMany(i => i);
}
```

LazyBuffer is a custom implemention of Buffer, which only returns a result set when new items are available, rather than returning empty result sets on the specified interval.
This is how I invoke it, it blows as described above.

```
BufferAndDispatchUntil(p => Update.Insert(p.Item1, UpdateFactory.CreateView(p.Item2)), _config.DispatcherScheduler, _ignore);
```

This is my clear call in a separate segment of the code running on separate thread.

```
_ignore.OnNext(new Unit());  
Update.Clear();
```

I would appreciate if you can help me figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can't stop "mid insert".  You need to lock your data structures when performing non-atomic operations to ensure data integrity.

```
lock(someObj)
{
    myList.Insert(i, obj);
}
```

Make sure to lock at the smallest resolution possible, i.e., don't lock an entire method if you need only protect against a single non-atomic operation.

That, or have you looked at [C#'s thread safe collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305.aspx) yet which handle much of the locking for you?

Comment: #ed-s (am butchering my replies) Basically I am concerned over all inserts following a clear. I am not concerned with the clear and insert conflicting. I am interested in stopping the inserts following the ignore event.

Comment: @GregB: I believe I answered that; you need to protect the insert with a mutex (`lock`).  Worst case; you insert an item and immediately clear it.  Is that so bad?  You want to stop the insert anyway.  Have you looked at the thread-safe collection classes yet?

Comment: @EdS. He's not inserting at the front of the list is the problem. He's inserting in random locations, which will throw up if the list is empty. He can simply be defensive and in the lock check the count before the insert. But I believe the whole design is broken and needs to use single queues to process everything, rather than trying to work directly against the list.

Comment: @yamen: I think you're 100% right.  I see a poor design as well... but honestly, I was too lazy to think out and write down a better alternative.

Comment: Gentlemen, the poor design could potentially stem from inserting into an index granted. However, the main issue is that I need to stop the flow of updates. Even if I Add, which is a safer operation as you mention, since I need to insert a new data snapshot, adding to a new snapshot would be the wrong thing to do.

Comment: @GregB better design means the problem wouldn't exist. For example, instead of doing all the jazz you're doing now, you could instead put the set of `Action` into a `BlockingCollection` (such as a queue), that then processes them on the dispatcher thread. When you want to 'reset' the list, you can also clear the `BlockingCollection` queue - that way you won't have any 'buffered' actions performed after you clear the list.

Comment: @yamen looks interesting. I am going to look into it now.

Answer (score 0):

You're undoing the guarantees that Rx provides you when you do this:

```
.Do(b => dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => b.ForEach(onNext), dispatcherPriority))
```

This is why you're hitting the bug, because you're queuing up stuff to run in the UI thread, but your Rx pipeline isn't aware of it, so you end up splitting.

Comment: I have a sneaky suspicion that you correct, could you elaborate further on the matter. I am trying to research the issue further myself.